# Does Rest Apis need to be implemented using http2 to be asynchronous?

Tags: http, http2

We are currently upgrading an API. Previously, the API would respond with a 200 status code for successful requests and utilize session IDs for authentication. In the new version of the API, the response is 202, and it employs JWT tokens for authentication.

Now, if someone claims that the older APIs were synchronous and the new APIs are asynchronous:

1. Does this imply that the new APIs are implemented using HTTP/2 since it is often associated with asynchronous behavior?
2. Is it possible that our request was received by the server and pushed into a processing queue but has not been successfully processed yet(we can call it also asynchronous), and the choice of HTTP version is irrelevant? If this is the case, why do we specifically attribute the asynchronous behavior to HTTP/2 and not mention that HTTP/1.1 can also exhibit asynchronous behavior? Which aspect of the asynchronous behavior in HTTP/2 are we referring to?

Answer (score 1):

HTTP/2 does not fundamentally change the underlying model, but it optimizes how requests and responses are transmitted. I can't think of anything that makes HTTP/2 more asynchronous than HTTP/1 is, other than that multiple requests and responses can be muliplexed over a single connection.

It shouldn't fundamentally change how APIs are built. Perhaps the only change in API design when using HTTP/2 instead of HTTP/1.1 might be that it's cheaper to do many HTTP requests, so you could potentially create more fine-grained endpoint over large combined ones.

So if you have a source for the conjecture that 'HTTP/2 is more asynchronous' it would be helpful to get a real quote or link with more context to better understand what the writer was thinking.

Answer (score 0):

What software is your Server made from? Async VS Sync rarely has anything to do with HTTP 1.1 VS 2. So for question #1 I'm going to say No.

A synchronous server would probably hang while it figures out how to response, while an Asynchronous server would not. Better to be async in that regard.

It maybe the case in the software you're using that HTTP1.1 vs 2 does matter, but it doesn't in NodeJS land and most Web Servers that I know of.

Comment: why do we say then http2 is asynchronous ?
https://thenewstack.io/take-advantage-http2-speed-web-sites-apps/

Comment: They are both asyncronous in any way I understand it. However http2 offers multiplexing and that sets it apart from HTTP1.1